# google is not defined in Gatsby js app for @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, gatsby

I am having issues with this npm package for gatsby @react-google-maps/api I am getting a google is not defined error. I know it has to do with Gatsby needing to set the variable to window.google, but I am not quite sure how to do that with this package.

Here is my code so far

```
import { LoadScript, GoogleMap } from "@react-google-maps/api"
const MapFooter = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey="fdsaf"
        region="EN"
        version="weekly"
      />
      <GoogleMap id="ground-example" zoom={13} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: My hunch is that the issue is with server-side rendering. Take a look at [Debugging HTML builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/), and if you're still stuck, please add more info to your question (error details, reproduction repo)

Comment: ok I'll give that a shot thanks

Comment: Hi @AndersKitson, i'm facing same issue. You found a solution? Theres a github demo and I'm trying to figure how to make this work with gatsby https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/tree/master/packages/react-google-maps-api-gatsby-example/src

Comment: Your LoadScript should not be self closing. It should wrap GoogleMap then close

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had  this one problem white package and i solved returning the version previous more precisely @react-google-maps/api": "^1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put `<GoogleMap></GoogleMap>` component INSIDE the `<LoadScript></LoadScript>` (I am using React 16 + GatsbyJs). The demo code puts these two components separately.